# Putting flexible question numbers in questions

Tags: c#, list

(Sorry for the weird question title, I don't really know how to word this)

I'm making a quiz for an assessment, it's a pretty simple multiple choice sort of deal. My problem stems from one of the requirements of the assessment, which states that you need to be able to add/remove questions to and from the list. The questions are easily removed, but the question's index is written as such:

`questions.Add("Q1: What is not recyclable among these options?\n1. Batteries\n2. Aluminum cans\n3. Glass\n4. Paper");`

Obviously there's nothing inherently wrong with this, but the list gets kind of strange after you've added or removed a few questions. What I want is to have the question's number appear in the question itself, and adjust the question numbers for the removal of a certain question. So if I have 5 questions (Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, and Q5), and I remove question 4, it will remove the question and print the numbers of the remaining questions accordingly (Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4, where Q4 is the same question as Q5 before Q4 was removed). It sounds fairly complex, but that's honestly all I want it to do. Something like this, where qn represents the question's number:

```
questions.Add("Q"+qn+": Here");
questions.Add("Q"+qn+": There");
questions.Add("Q"+qn+": Everywhere");
Console.WriteLine(questions);
// Remove question two
questions.Add("Q"+qn+": Here");
questions.Add("Q"+qn+": Everywhere");
Console.WriteLine(questions);

Output:

Q1: Here
Q2: There
Q3: Everywhere

// Q2 gets removed

Q1: Here
Q2: Everywhere
```

Comment: Couldn't you compute the question numbers as you print the questions?

Comment: if you start with three questions, remove one, then add two more, why are there only two in the end?

Comment: @ScottHunter I'm not quite sure what you mean.

Comment: I would point out that your questions do not actually have numbers. Not as immutable identifiers, anyway. The numbers here indicate the *position* of the question within a list., and only have meaning in that context Which tells me that the question number should not be stored with the question itself.

Comment: @RufusL They're not getting added in. All of the questions are part of the same list, called `questions`. One of the questions gets removed, leaving the remaining two.

Comment: In your sample code, you call the `Add` method `5` times.

Comment: @RufusL Sorry, that's not what I meant. The questions are still in the list, they're not getting added in later. I just wanted to demonstrate that one of the questions in the list was removed.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution is to **NOT** store the `"Q1"` portion with the question, and simply use the `index` of the question in the list when you want to display the questions.

For example:

```
// We don't store the question number with the question
var questions = new List<string> {"Here", "There", "Everywhere"};

for (int i = 0; i < questions.Count; i++)
{
    // Instead we write the question numbers as we print the list
    Console.WriteLine($"Q{i + 1}: {questions[i]}");
}

Console.WriteLine("\nRemoving question #2...\n");
questions.RemoveAt(1);

for (int i = 0; i < questions.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Q{i + 1}: {questions[i]}");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: ahh you beat me by 27 seconds

Comment: Well I guess I'm a bit of an idiot, because I didn't think of that. I tried it out, and it works like a charm. Thank you.